# source .bashrc on vagrant

Tags: bash, vagrant

I needed to modify .bashrc to set node path file on vagrant and I guess made a mistake. I sourced it and my vagrant became paralyzed. I'm trying to fix the .bashrc but now vagrant can't run any normal linux commands like vi or cd. How can I modify .bashrc without destroying the box? When I ssh to vagrant I get this

```
/usr/bin/which: no virtualenvwrapper.sh in (/home/vagrant/node_modules)
-bash: source: filename argument required
source: usage: source filename [arguments]
-bash: awk: command not found
-bash: awk: command not found
```

My setup is centos vagrant box on Mac.

Comment: To fix it you may do `scp user@remote_machine:/etc/skel/.bashrc user@remote_machine:/home/user/.bashrc`

Comment: Maybe try a shell provisioner to remove your `.bashrc` in your Vagrantfile? Shell provisioner should default to `/bin/sh` and should not be affected by any bash init files.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to modify a file on your Vagrant machine, I recommended using Vagrant's [file provisioner](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/file.html). If your provisioning needs are more complex, then you should consider other provisioners such as Puppet or Chef.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I modified the Vagrant file to enable virtualbox gui.

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.memory = 6144
  v.cpus = 4
  v.gui = true
end
```

Then in the virtualbox terminal that popped up, I logged in as root. The root user wasn't paralyzed like vagrant user was. I then opened the vagrant's user .bashrc file by going to `/home/vagrant/` deleted the line that was causing issue. Exited root and logged in as vagrant and everything started to work normally